# Pass parameters to Junit 5 TestRunner extension

Tags: selenium, webdriver, junit5, browser-automation

Trying to figure out how to pass some parameters to my custom implementation of TestWatcher in Junit5.  The base class for all tests is set to @ExtendWith with the TestWatcher.  Trying to keep it as simple as possible and I can't seem to find a straightforward answer on how to do this

Comment: You would do well to show us what you've tried so far as people on SO are more inclined to help those that have attempted to help themselves.  Expand your question with any code you've tried so far.

Comment: This is more of a "is it possible" question than anything to do with my own code.  I'm performing a major refactor and have been hung up trying to pass a few variables to the class and haven't found much documentation on this.  I've looked into the Parameterized annotations, but those seem more geared towards running the same tests with different variables.  Just looking to pass from the Before and BeforeEach methods to the extension.  I haven't been able to find a way to pass variables from the class that is annotated with the ExtendWith annotation

Comment: I've been trying to leverage the ExtensionContext Store to pass the parameters but I'm not sure if this is the right track

Comment: The need to hand in specific values suggests that an extension may not be the right tool. Using a plain test helper object may suit your needs and is also simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling on a similar problem, basically I needed a global parameter (a separator string data) for the annotation @DisplayNameGenerator().

Because the lack of code examples of how you're trying to resolve this I'm gonna explain my approach of how to get a parameter provided by the user and see if it works for you,

I created a interface with the return of the String value that is my custom parameter that I wanted to get from the user,

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@API(status = EXPERIMENTAL, since = "5.4")
public @interface IndicativeSentencesSeparator {

    String value();
}
```

So this way I could create my test with this new interface, and passing the parameter but also making it optional to use, like this,

```
@DisplayName("My Test")
@DisplayNameGeneration(DisplayNameGenerator.IndicativeSentencesGenerator.class)
@IndicativeSentencesSeparator(" --> ")
class MyTestClass { //Some test methods and stuff }
```

To get the this new class in the implementation, I used the java method `class.getAnnotation(classType)` in the class that you're trying to extract the value, sending by parameter the class to find, in this case the interface I created.

```
IndicativeSentencesSeparator separator =
myTestClass.getAnnotation(IndicativeSentencesSeparator.class);
```

And finally to get the parameter used the getter `value`,

```
String parameter = separator.value();
```